# ADF JDeveloper: Change output files directory

Tags: git, oracle-adf, gitignore, jdeveloper

I'm working with a team in an app built with Java ADF, and JDeveloper.

The problem is that since we're using Git, JDeveloper generates ouput files every time we run the application, these files are such as: .class, .jbd, among others. However, somehow we can't get Git to ignore those files. I was thinking maybe I can change JDeveloper's output folder that way I could ignore all that's inside  of it.

Is this possible? If not, are any other workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

First, add them to your `.gitignore`.

```
*.class
*.jbd
# All other extensions you want
```

Then, remove the newly gitignored files with

```
git rm -r --cached .
```

Note that you can remove a specific file by replacing `.` with the file extension.

Comment: No.  For uncommitted changes, a gitignore is enough to not even need to do anything else.  Git will automatically ignore everything in the gitignore file .  However, if you have committed a `.class` file and want to remove it, you can add it to the git ignore and then run `git rm -r --cached .`  If you need to remove uncommitted changes, just `git reset` after creating the git ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You can control JDeveloper output directories in project properties->Project Source Path.

That being said this shouldn't be an issue if you'll use the built in Git integration in JDeveloper that seems to ignore these files (as part of the "version application" menu)